# InAppBrowser (PhoneGap Build 3.1.0) events do not fire on Android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I am using PhoneGap Build to wrap an AngularJS project as a mobile app, it uses InAppBrowser to open Facebook/Twitter OAuth page.

My configuration:

- Angular 1.0.8
- PhoneGap 3.1.0 on PhoneGap Build
- InAppBrowser 0.2.3
- Tested with hydration enabled and disabled, same result

Here is the code snippet I used:

```
// This part code is called from click handler of a button,
// this is the only place that used the PhoneGap API.
var ipwin; // Used in somewhere else
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    ipwin = $window.open("some url", "_blank");
    $(ipwin).on("loadstop", function(e) {
        var url = e.originalEvent.url;
        console.log("loadstop: " + url);
        // snipped
    });
    // Below are testing code added while debugging
    var test = function() {
        console.log("setTimeout test");
    };
    setTimeout(test, 2000);
    test();
}, false);
```

This works fine on Android 4.0, however on Android 2.3 the `loadstop` event does not fire. I also tried `loadstart` and `loaderror`, none of them fires. More strangely, `setTimeout test` only appears in console output once instead of twice. Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some refactor and changes to the app, the problem is mysteriously gone. Not entirely sure but I think it is because some other scripts in the page conflicted with cordova.js.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing similar problems with both PhoneGap 3.0 and 3.1 on Android, reverting to PhoneGap 2.9 made these InAppBrowser events fire again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be a problem with the last phonegap/cordova version 3.1.0.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/e5_5unC2fYs

Try an older version.

Answer (score 0):

this issue happened to me and I did these steps to solve it:

- Upgrade your Phonegap version to 3.1
- Create a new project
- Add your platforms then your plugins
- Copy your code again back to www

this should solve your problem

Comment: I am already using PhoneGap 3.1, and I build the project on PhoneGap Build, so I think this is irrelevant.

Comment: is your cordova.js file 3.1 too or still 3.00, please check it?

Comment: I had this issue when I upgraded phonegap to 3.1 then build an old project which had version 3

Comment: cordova.js is inserted by PhoneGap Build automatically so this shouldn't matter. Anyways, I opened the apk package and confirmed it was 3.1.